# Meaning of 'train' in 19th c. women's clothing--but not the elongated part of a dress, robe, or coat

Tags: etymology

Queen Victoria instructed her secretary to write Princess Alexandra about her trousseau before she married the Prince of Wales: "Three or four trains and *grand toilettes* will . . . be sufficient." What's a "train," in this context? Is it a long undergarment such as a slip, or something else?

Comment: Why would it not be the *train* to a formal dress?

Comment: Note that "grand toilettes", in this context, means "formal dresses", so it's reasonable to assume that "trains" are somehow associated with the dresses.

Comment: _OED_ definiton: "An elongated back of a robe or skirt, **or a separate long piece of material attached at the back of formal dress**, which trails behind on the ground."

Comment: What makes you think it's *not* the elongated part of a dress—or that there is any answer that isn't that?

Comment: I think a "train and grand toilette" is one thing, of which the Queen wanted three or four. Whether the train is part of the dress or attached separately is probably not a design matter which is not really on-topic here. What did your research tell you about what a *train* (in the context of women's dresses) is?

Answer (score 2):

[Train](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/train) :

(DRESS) a part of a long dress that spreads out over the ground behind the person wearing it.

> a wedding dress with a long train. (Lexico)

[image]

(nzBridal.com)